# Using Javascript to store an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have a form submitted, and store elements of it as variables in Javascript. Here's the HTML:

```
<form id ="form" onSubmit="JavaScript:ScriptJS()">
        <label for ="zip">ZipCode: </label>
        <br/>
        <input type="number" name = "zip" id = "zip">
        <br/>
        <label for ="type">Cancer Type: </label>
        <select name ="type" id = "ctype">
            <option value ="a">A</option>
            <option value ="b">B</option>
            <option value ="c">C</option>
        </select>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" id ="submit">
    </form>
```

And here's the Javascript that I'm trying to use:

```
function Submit(){
    const zipCode = document.getElementsById("zip");
    const cType = document.getElementsById("ctype");
}
console.log(ZipCode);
console.log(CType);
```

VS code is telling me that the constants are not defined. Help anyone?
Thank you

Comment: VSCode is correct; your constants are only defined within the scope of the `Submit()` function. Why are you trying to log the values outside of that function anyway?

Answer (score 2):

There are *a variety* of things wrong here...

1. The function is called `getElementById`, not `getElementsById`
2. You're defining the constants in the function, so you can only reference them in the function.
3. You have to reference them by the same name you used when defining them.
4. You never invoke the `Submit()` function.
5. If the form is reloading the page, everything client-side is lost anyway.

Correcting each one...

```js
function Submit(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // 5
  const zipCode = document.getElementById("zip"); // 1
  const cType = document.getElementById("ctype"); // 1
  console.log(zipCode); // 2 & 3
  console.log(cType); // 2 & 3
}
```

```html
<form id ="form" onsubmit="Submit(event)"> <!-- 4 -->
  <label for ="zip">ZipCode: </label>
  <br/>
  <input type="number" name = "zip" id = "zip">
  <br/>
  <label for ="type">Cancer Type: </label>
  <select name ="type" id = "ctype">
    <option value ="a">A</option>
    <option value ="b">B</option>
    <option value ="c">C</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id ="submit">
</form>
```

Of course, preventing the form from submitting will do exactly that.  So it's not entirely clear what the *end goal* is here.  So I suppose that change is optional, as you'll still see what's logged to the console if the page reloads as long as your debugging tools are configured to retain the console history.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the feedback! I caught the getelementbyid on my own shortly after I posted this. I am trying to upon having the data submitted in the form, have some stuff pop up depending on what is entered into the form. I was trying to log the values outside of the function just to test to make sure that it was working. Its probably apparent that my Javascript, which was never fantastic has gotten pretty rusty. Thanks again!